# Detect in jQuery mouse entered into a child element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is there in jQuery any function what can return `true` or `false` if mouse entered into their child element?

I look to something what I can use like this:

```
if ( $(this).mouseIsOnChild() ) {
    // mouse is on a child element
} else {
    // mouse leaved branch of HTML tree
}
```

Of courese `.mouseIsOnChild()` function is not exists. Yet.

Comment: You may also comment on why you need to do something like this

Comment: I want to detect where is mouse when leave the actual element to show and hide other elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside the event handler - you can check if `e.target` (`e` is the argument passed in the event handler function) is the current element that triggered the event using [.is()](http://api.jquery.com/is/)

```
if($(this).children('div').is(e.target)){ 
// replacing $(this).children('div') with the children element selector
}else{

}
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/95nnn/)

If you are looking not for a specific children but any children you can do something like this

```
if($('>*',this).is(e.target)){
    // do something if it's children
}else{

}
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/6DXx9/)

Answer (score 1):

```
//track hover state    
$('*').hover(function() {
            $(this).data('hover', true); 
        }, function() {
            $(this).data('hover', false);
        });

//plugin to check whether mouse is on children
$.fn.mouseIsOnChild = function() {
    var ret = false;
    $(this).children().each(function() {
            ret = $(this).data('hover');
            return ret ? false : true;
        });
    return ret;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The [`mouseenter()`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/) and [`mouseleave()`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/) events exist.

Using this we can construct a data structure that checks for if a mouse is in a child's area:

```
$(function() {
    var isIn = false;
    $(target).children().mouseenter(function() {isIn = true;});
    $(target).children().mouseleave(function() {isIn = false;});

    var isMouseIn = function() { return isIn; };
});
```

now, your function `isMouseIn()` returns true if the mouse is inside the child, false otherwise.

If you wanted to get fancy, you could attach custom data to the `target` node instead of a global variable.  I will leave that as an exercise for the motivated.

Comment: How to tell me these functions the mouse is over a child element?

Comment: `$(this).children().mouseenter()`